# How to make a HTML file on Apache webserver accessible from other devices and locations via a web browser

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, apache2, html

**[I have already installed and set up Apache2; this is not a duplicate question, please see below]**

I have uploaded a HTML file to the Apache2 localhost web server, using the default :8000 port. I want this file to be accessible via a web browser on another device in another location, by entering a WWW domain into a search engine. In other words, I want to create a fully accessible website while keeping the HTML files for my website on the Apache web server.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Place the file like this `/var/www/html/index.html`. Then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, here create a file index.conf and add the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAdmin info@test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

As I did forgot and E. Yagmahan mentioned save your file and run this command:

```
sudo a2ensite index.conf
```

This command will enable your configuration file.

After all that run this:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. By the way, I was advise by a friend who does CS not to use the :80 port, and to use another one instead. Is he right, or is there any reason in not wanting to use the :80 port?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html read this. Port 80 is used for http making it a reserve port.

Comment: @RuairíMásún if you intend `http://domain.tld/` to go directrly to the site you need to use port 80.  Your friend who does "CS" is not familiar with IT networking, but they're probably trying to shield you from *typical* HTTP based attack vectors and port scanners, but that's just security through obscurity and is useless in the long run.  (FYI: I'm an IT Security professional so I'm speaking from some levels of experience here.)

Comment: If you have a *custom application* that does not run as `root` or doesn't get served directly by Apache, then *yes* you would use port 8000.  But that's not the case when Apache itself is serving the files.

Comment: I can't create a new file in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory directly. Am I able to do this using Terminal? If so, how do I do it? I've opened the Terminal in that directory.

Comment: Yes it is done using terminal. Go to this directory `etc/apache2/sites-available` and type `sudo nano index.conf`. Once you have added contents in the file press `Ctrl+O` to save it.

Comment: @thirteen3054 I am having trouble doing this still. I have followed all of the steps you have made, in this order:

First, I created the index.conf file in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory by opening the Terminal there and going "touch index.conf" (I had already put my index.html file in the /var/www/html/ directory).

Then, I opened the Terminal again in the same place and ran this command: sudo a2ensite index.conf

Comment: @thirteen3054 Then, I ran this command in a new Terminal window:

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAdmin info@test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

And finally, I ran this command:

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: @thirteen3054 
However, this didn't work. When I enter my localhost address (127.0.0.1) it just opens the file as before (http://127.0.0.1) and I can't give it a web address. Do you have any other suggestions I can make?

Comment: @E. Yagmahan 
The steps above did not work. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @RuairíMásún you are not to run `<VirtualHost *80>...</VirtualHost>` I did not said that. this snippet needs to be in index.conf file. After that run `sudo a2ensite index.conf` in same directory.

Comment: @thirteen3054 How do I edit the file once it's in the etc/apache2/sites-available directory? I open the file using a text editor, and when I try to save the updates, it says permission denied. I assume there is some way I can do this using the Terminal with a sudo command.

Comment: from terminal go to the `sites-available` and and type `sudo nano index.conf`

Comment: @thirteen3054 Thanks for your help so far. I have created an index.conf file in the sites-available directory with all of the information you suggested and have run the suggested commands after that. However, when I search in the URL bar for 127.0.0.1 the web page comes up as a normal directory still. How do I make the webpage accessible via a WWW domain?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers of thirteen3054:

After creating the new file index.conf you should enable it via:

```
sudo a2ensite index.conf
```

Doing that enables the specified site within the apache2 configuration. It does this by creating symlinks within /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. (Likewise, "a2dissite" disables a site by removing those symlinks.)

Answer (score 0):

Place the file like this /var/www/html/index.html. Then go to /etc/apache2/sites-available, here create a file index.conf and add the following

ServerName test.com
        ServerAdmin info@test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

save your file and run this command:

sudo a2ensite index.conf
This command will enable your configuration file.

After all that run this:
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart